# Angular conditional display using ng-if/ng-show/ng-switch briefly shows both elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show either element A or B based on the value of a boolean, but when the value switches, both elements are shown briefly, using ng-if:

```
<div ng-if="a"></div>
<div ng-if="!a"></div>
```

This also happens when I use ng-show/ng-hide:

```
<div ng-show="a"></div>
<div ng-hide="a"></div>
```

And even ng-switch:

```
<div ng-switch="a || 'false'">
   <div ng-switch-default></div>
   <div ng-switch-when="false"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to enforce only one of those elements being shown at the same time, or it this just not possible?

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle or some demo?

Comment: When I create an isolated example, everything works fine, but only in the context of my application it breaks down.

Answer (score 1):

(Late answer for late people like me.)

I'm guessing the project uses `ngAnimate` that causes these kinds of issues.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938021/angular-ng-if-or-ng-show-responds-slow-2second-delay) has several answers, ranging from removing `ngAnimate`, changing related CSS and switching to using `ngClass`.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120025/angularjs-nghide-delayed-with-ngshow) has an answer suggesting to configure animations with `$animateProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<div ng-show="a == true">A</div>
<div ng-show="a == false">B</div>


<div ng-switch="a || 'false'">
   <div ng-switch-default>A</div>
   <div ng-switch-when="false">B</div>
</div>

<button ng-click="a = !a">Switch {{a}}</button>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz384982/4/)

Comment: This works fine, but in my application there seems to be latency